# D3 Transform Rescale X jumps to right

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I'm creating a timeline line chart showing 5 or 6 different lines and want to be able to zoom in and scroll (once zoomed). I used some examples that use area charts but for some reason my line chart jumps to the right when I zoom the first time and I lose some of the data off to the right (I can no longer scroll to see it or see it when zoomed fully out). Also the lines appear over the y axis when I zoom or scroll.

I've copied it to JSFiddle ([see here](https://jsfiddle.net/1tx3p5qa/)) with a dataset from 1 of the lines in my chart. Why is the line jumping to the right as soon as you use the zoom function? How can I stop the line from appearing over the y-axis?

Here is the JS of my version if you'd prefer to read it here:

```
function drawTimeline() {

    var margin = {top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 50, left: 60}
    var width = d3.select('#timeline').node().getBoundingClientRect().width/3*2;
    var height = 300;

    var svg = d3.select("#timeline").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height+margin.top+margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
        .call(d3.zoom()
                // .extent()
                .scaleExtent([1, 10])
                .translateExtent([[0, -Infinity], [width - margin.left - margin.right, Infinity]])
                .on("zoom", zoom)
        );

    var view = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "view")
        .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("fill", "white");

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([
                d3.min(poll_data[0].avgpolls, function(p) { return p.date; }), 
                d3.max(poll_data[0].avgpolls, function(p) { return p.date; })
            ])
            .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([50, 0])
            .range([0, height]);


    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    var gX = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "axis xaxis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    var gY = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis yaxis")
                .call(yAxis);

    //All lines are drawn in the same way (x and y points)
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.poll); });

    //selectAll allows us to create and manipulate multiple groups at once
    var party = svg.selectAll(".party")
        .data(poll_data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "party");

    //Add path to every country group at once
    var pollPaths = party.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.avgpolls); })
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return returnPartyColour(d.party); });

    function zoom() {
      console.log("zooming: " + d3.event.transform);
      var new_x = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
      gX.call(d3.axisBottom(new_x));
      //view.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);

      //Redraw lines
      //pollPaths.select(".line").attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.avgpolls); });
      var newline = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return new_x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.poll); });

      pollPaths.attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.avgpolls); });
    }

}
```

The data is formatted like this in my version but not the JSFiddle:

```
poll_data = [
    {
        'party' : 'Party 1',
        'avgpolls' : [
            {'date' : new Date(year, month, day), 'poll' : 0, },
        ],

]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things required to fix these issues.

The reason the line was jumping on zoom was because the zoom extent was not set. This was set and the value of translateExtent updated:

```
d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width - margin.left - margin.right, Infinity]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width - margin.left - margin.right, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoom)
```

To prevent the paths from overflowing a clipping path is required. After creating the svg, before other elements are added, I added a clip-path as follows:

```
svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    //Same dimensions as the area for the lines to appear
    .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
    .attr("height", height);
```

Then this had to be added to each path.

```
var pollPaths = party.append("path")
    ...
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
```

The original JSFiddle has been [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/1tx3p5qa/6/) to reflect these changes.